# Could "Generation Z" be the most conservative one since WW2?

Tags: sociology

I've found several sources that explain that ["Generation Z"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Z) could be the most conservative one since the end of WW2.

Some of the sources, are the ones that follow:

Dailymail: [They don't like drugs or gay marriage, and they HATE tattoos: Is 'Generation Z' the most conservative since WW2?](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3790614/They-don-t-like-drugs-gay-marriage-HATE-tattoos-Generation-Z-conservative-WW2.html)

CNSnews: [The Next Generation of Americans (Gen Z) May Be the Most Conservative Since WWII](https://www.cnsnews.com/commentary/eric-metaxas/next-generation-americans-gen-z-may-be-most-conservative-wwii)

ChristianPost: [Generation Z Most Conservative Since WWII?](https://www.christianpost.com/news/generation-z-most-conservative-since-wwii.html)

Personally, I clearly see "Generation Z" easily being more conservative than ["Millenials"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennials), I still consider possible them being more conservative than ["Generation X"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_X), but still quite a stretch, but in no way to be more conservative than ["Baby boomers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers).

Is the claim I'm mentioning backed up by reliable data that shows that "Generation Z" could be with a considerable probability more conservative than the other mentioned generations?

Comment: My impression was that Gen Z were further to the *left*, not the right. I'd definitely want to see data from a source less biased than the Daily Mail.

Comment: I have no data, but you might want to reconsider levels of conservative in your mental model, taking into account the effects of age.  Back in the day, "Baby Boomers" were known as "hippies".

Comment: Also... the answer to this sort of question depends radically on your idea of what "conservative" and "liberal" mean.  Right now, they're umbrella terms for political teams.  On the actual issues, there are often arguments abotu which ones are more important, and which ones matter at all.  Can you even give us a definition of "conservative" that isn't largely arbitrary?

Comment: The guy who wrote the CNSNews article was also talking about how the core of conservatism was great, but they needed to really get out there and inculcate the new generation with all of the other conservative causes of the day.  His bias was pretty blatant.  ChristianPost... I didn't really check that one out, but the name sort of speaks for itself.

Comment: As far as I can see, this all is coming from two sources.  One was a survey, performed in England, and no longer available online.  The other is exit polling from the 2016 US elections, for the few that are old enough to vote and did vote.

Comment: The CNSNews story and the ChristianPost article are mostly the same story by one author. It appears that he simply rewrote small parts of it.

Comment: @BenBarden Not nearly all Boomers were hippies, although the hippie movement was well publicized (including a painfully bad depiction in a Star Trek episode).  Lots of Boomers were relatively conservative; they just didn't get the publicity.

Comment: I am concerned this entire question depends on your definition of "conservative". (One of the articles talks about tattoos and body piercings, which seems to be more about fashion - and not wanting to look like 30-somethings - than any reasonable definition of "conservative").

Comment: @Oddthinking, I guess we can consider "conservative" what goes in opposite direction of what today is considered "progressive", I mean things like abortion prohibition, what's considered normal is being heterosexual, other sexual tendencies are just... weird, man in the role of working and giving money to support a family, women in the role of taking care of the house and the children, family union is important so, even the impossibility to get a divorce, and no laws that help on breaking a family, strict education and well... I think the point is clear.

Comment: "Progressive" is also ill-defined... and even when you laundry-list it, you're not making clear what the relative importance of things is.  I'm not convinced you *could*, at anything past a hand-waving level.  This is one of those areas of endeavor that's designed to go off of gut feelings.  As far as I can tell, a tendency to conflate stuff like this is literally built into our genes.

Comment: "When asked to comment on same-sex marriage, transgender rights and cannabis legislation, 59 per cent of Generation X teenagers said they had conservative views."  Does that mean they literally asked "Do you have conservative views", or does it mean "We asked them what their views were, and we classified their responses as 'conservative'"?

Comment: If the former, how much of that is changing moors as to what is "conservative"? 50 years ago, the idea that gay people shouldn't be put in prison was "liberal". So anyone raised in that culture who doesn't think gay people should be put in prison may very well consider themselves to be "liberal".

Comment: If it's the latter, then saying what views were expressed and which were classified as "conservative" is a rather critical part of reporting the results. Today, the idea that gay people should be left  And what does "more than 10 per cent of teenagers were more likely to avoid tattoos." mean? And did they compare the views of teenage millennials to the views that Gen Xers had when they were teenagers, or to what views they have now?

Comment: @Accumulation, yes, obviously from previous points of views, what was considered liberal before now can be considered even extremely conservative. But an absolute scale can be set, for example, between asking for death penalty for homosexuality and promoting it, and saying that people is weird if the haven't tried homosexuality, promoting it, and even privileging homosexuals, there's a huge quantity of gray shades, millenials are likely more near to the second than the first, so if Gen Z just asked for "just let them free", they'd be way more conservative than millenials.

Comment: @user2638180 Are you actually claiming that millennials are generally in favor of giving homosexuals special privileges?  Do you have any source for that?  I don't think I've seen anyone arguing that gays and lesbians should get special privileges, just the ones heterosexuals have.

Comment: @user2638180 ive read the article and it seems very biased, being laced with many dog whistle words. here on skeptics stackexchange we should really hold ourselves to a much higher standards than linking religious sites.

Comment: @AnkurS we have higher standards for what we cite in answers, than for providing examples of claims in questions.

Comment: I've started a bounty because I too couldn't find any accesible sources that would resolve the question clearly. I hope I'll get a broader answer, not only to the question in the title

Comment: I think the "Personally" paragraph does not belong in the question.

Comment: @Probably half the problem is that the claim isn't at all well-defined.  If it were well-defined, we could seek out and find evidence one way or the other.  Does "conservative" mean "likely to vote Republican"?  "Likely to self-identify as conservative"?  What are we talking about here?

Comment: I went ham on this question.  The three websites were basing their entire claim on an internet quiz and not any kind of real polling.  The kind of internet quiz where you find out which one of the Backstreet Boys you are or which character from Game of Thrones your farts say about you. I cited an actual poll from the Pew Research Center that also shows that it's most likely the opposite is true, that Generation Z is very similar to Millennials

Comment: A big problem you have is that "conservative" is a very poorly-defined term (as is "liberal").

Answer (score 17):

**All three articles are basing their claim off an internet quiz and not an actual poll.  Evidence points to this Quiz being not scientific in any way and its results should be ignored.  An actual poll on conservative vs. liberal views broken down by Generation was done by the Pew Research Center which shows that members of Generation Z are very similar to Millennials in their views on**

- **LGBTQ rights (including marriage, gender neutral pronouns, and non-binary humans)**
- **Global Warming**
- **Racial Disparity in the United States (including views on National Anthem protests)**
- **The Role of Goverment in solving problems**
- **Racial and Ethnic Diversity (including Interracial Marriage)**

**In addition, there is evidence that members of Generation Z who are registered as Republicans (the conservative party in the United States) are more left-leaning than Republicans from other generations.**

---

For the purposes of this question, we will be relying on the Wikipedia definition of [Conservatism in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism_in_the_United_States).

> Conservatism in the United States is a broad system of political beliefs in the United States that is characterized by respect for American traditions, republicanism, support for Judeo-Christian values, moral universalism, pro-business and anti-labor union, anti-communism, individualism, advocacy of American exceptionalism, and a defense of Western culture from the perceived threats posed by socialism, authoritarianism, and moral relativism. Liberty is a core value, as it is with all major American parties. American conservatives consider individual liberty—within the bounds of American values—as the fundamental trait of democracy; this perspective contrasts with that of modern American liberals, who generally place a greater value on equality and social justice and emphasize the need for state intervention to achieve these goals. American conservatives believe in limiting government in size and scope, and in a balance between national government and states' rights. Apart from some libertarians, they tend to favor strong action in areas they believe to be within government's legitimate jurisdiction, particularly national defense and law enforcement. Social conservatives oppose abortion and same-sex marriage, while privileging traditional marriage and supporting Christian prayer in public schools.

---

The articles you cited above are basing their headline on a single internet Quiz from a company called [The Gild](https://www.the-gild.com/).

> And get this: According to one British study conducted by global consultancy firm, **The Guild**, almost sixty percent of Gen Z respondents in the U.K. described their views on "same-sex marriage, transgender rights and marijuana legalization" as "conservative" or "moderate," compared with a whopping 83% of Millennials who called themselves "quite" or "very liberal" on these issues. The Gen Z participants were even ten times more likely than Millennials to dislike tattoos and body piercings!
>
> - ChristianPost.com
>
> And get this: According to one British study conducted by global consultancy firm, **The Guild**, almost sixty percent of Gen Z respondents in the U.K. described their views on “same-sex marriage, transgender rights and marijuana legalization” as “conservative” or “moderate,” compared with a whopping 83 percent of Millennials who called themselves “quite” or “very liberal” on these issues. The Gen Z participants were even ten times more likely than Millennials to dislike tattoos and body piercings!
>
> - CNSNews.com
>
> Only 14 and 15-year-olds were surveyed, by brand consultancy **The Gild**, as they were classed as being able to form credible opinions by that age.
>
> - DailyMail

It should be noted that all three of these outlets are rated Right/Extremely Right on [MediaBiasFactCheck.com](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/)

- [Daily Mail](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/daily-mail/) - Right Wing
- [CNS News](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/cns-news/) - Right/Extreme Right Wing
- [Christian Post](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/christian-post/) - Right Wing

The Gild (note that the Christian Post and the CNS News websites both misspell the name but are certainly talking about the same company) describes itself on its own website not as a polling company but as

> (...)a strategic brand consultancy with a mission to positively impact culture & commerce through a blend of art & science. We specialise in insight, innovation, strategy & creative.

The link to the Quiz seems to be permanently down, as I was able to track down what appears to be the link to it to https://www.the-gild.com/generation-quiz, but as of 11 November 2019 is returning a 404 error.

The only place I was able to find a description of the Quiz was on a website for a  consulting company called [After the Millennials](http://afterthemillennials.com/why-generation-z-is-not-more-conservative/).  They self describe their on their [About](http://afterthemillennials.com/about-anne/) page as follows.

> After the Millennials is the first and only consultant service established specifically to understand Generation Z – now and in the future. Sometimes called Generation Z, iGen, Plurals or the Homeland Generation, we still don’t know which name will “stick”. But we can’t let this stop us from preparing for the tsunami of change they represent.
>
> Driven by a voracious intellectual appetite for learning how different people tick, I have studied this youngest generation since they were first conceived. Understanding people helps us see new emerging trends and patterns. Analyzing our existing environments and stakeholders helps us envision, plan and prepare better for the future.
>
> A combination of data analytics, content analysis, strategic foresight, and generational theory can help us see important trends, sometimes years before they happen. This custom-made interdisciplinary approach has allowed me allows me to help a variety of companies prepare for tomorrow. My research has brought me to numerous countries on 3 different continents as a keynote speaker and quoted by media outlets such as BBC Capital, El Pais, Deutsche Welle, The Verge, Vox, Motherboard and more.

---

From their description of the Quiz.

> As soon as I landed on The Gild’s website I was invited to partake in the very same survey. **No filter question to make sure I met sampling criteria or any other requirements were needed to participate.** The Gild prepped my motivation by telling me: **“Big Business and Governments are stereotyping you into one of six generational groups” and, “At The Gild, we think that’s wrong and needs to stop, so we’ve designed this Generation Quiz to prove or disprove our theory, and we need your help.”** So as the freedom-loving, justice-seeking arm-chair activist I am, I was ready! I’d show those Big Businesses and Governments they can’t pigeonhole me or create mind-controlling Newspeak based on my generation or my preferences!
>
> First I was asked to compare statements and pick the one from each category I agreed the most with. **Since the statements were double-barreled and categories were overlapping, I had a hard time finding a statement that fit me.** None of the 5 answer alternatives managed to capture my preferences and idiosyncrasies. **But the biggest puzzle to me was: How do they get teenagers with 8-second attention spans to read through questions with five long winded answer alternatives like: “My main focus is on being fit and healthy, enjoying life and spending quality time with my family.”?** Having designed a few nation-wide surveys aimed at this age cohort myself, I’ve learned to keep the butcher knife close, chopping up and eliminating even the tiniest part of bad meat from my sentences to accommodate this easily distracted target group.
>
> (...)
>
> **But the funniest part was, when the survey was over I could just refresh the page and do it all over again! No IP address detector to block me from taking it twice. Even more, I was encouraged to share it over my social networks, ensuring that my echo-chamber could eliminate any tiny element of random selection mechanism that might have otherwise existed.**

***This wasn't a survey.  This was an internet quiz that you'd see shared on Facebook where you'd answer questions trying to figure out which character you'd be from Game of Thrones.***

---

To offer as a counterpoint, the [Pew Research Center](https://www.pewresearch.org/) published an article on 19 January 2019 titled [Generation Z Looks a Lot Like Millennials on Key Social and Political Issues](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2019/01/17/generation-z-looks-a-lot-like-millennials-on-key-social-and-political-issues/).  I'm not gonna quote each individual word on this article, because I could very easily quote the entire thing.  I strongly suggest you read the article in its entirety, but for the sake of posterity I will include some of the relevant data points from the article here.

- 30% of Gen Z approves of President Trump, below Gen X, Boomer, and Silent Generations but slightly higher than Millennials
- 70% of Gen Z believes the goverment should do more to solve problems, higher than  all other generations
- 62% of Gen Z believes that increasing racial/ethic diversity is good for society, higher than all other generations.

[image]

- 35% of Gen Z personally know someone who prefers gender-neutral pronouns

[image]

- 43% of Gen Z Republicans say that African Americans are treated less fairly than Whites, below any Democrat generations but well above all Republican generations.

[image]

- 70% of Gen Z think the government should do more to solve problems versus doing less and leaving problems to businesses and individuals, higher than all other generations

[image]

- 54% of Gen Z believe the Earth is getting warmer due to Human activity, below Millennials but above all other generations
- 14% believe the Earth is getting warmer due to Natural Weather patterns, below all other generations
- 10% believe there is no evidence the planet is getting warmer, above Millennials but below all other generations
- 22% not sure, highest of all generations

[image]

- 14% of Gen Z believes the US is better than all other countries in the world, second lowest only to Millennials
- 56% of Gen Z believes the US is one of the best countries, along with some others, lower than all generations other than the Silent Generation
- 30% of Gen Z believes there are other countries better than the US, higher than all generations

[image]

- 61% approve of NFL players choosing to kneel during the national anthem as a form of protest, lower than Millennials but above all other groups

[image]

- 62% of Gen Z say increasing racial and ethic diversity is a good thing for society, higher than all other generations.

[image]

- 48% of Gen Z say LGBTQ marriages are a good thing for society, higher than all other generations
- 15% of Gen Z say LGBTQ marriages are a bad thing for society, tied with Millennials and lower than all other generations
- 53% of Gen Z say interracial marriages are a good thing for society, tied with Millennials and higher than all other generations
- 4% of Gen Z say interracial marriages are a bad thing for society, tied with Millennials and lower than all other generations

[image]

- 50% of Gen Z say society is not accepting enough of people who do not identify as a man or a woman, higher than all generations
- 23% of Gen Z say society is too accepting of people who do not identify as a man or a woman, lower than all generations

[image]

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't care about these weird polls but about their claims. And I've read this Pew research but they didn't really answer the question regarding conservative/liberal inclination sufficiently. Thank you.

Comment: @Probably I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant to say I've read the study you copied here and I didn't find the answer. These questions aim at the progressive x reactionist distinction. Left and right is about what the government should do and the only question asking that is ambiguous ("bigger role of the government" could be interpreted as economically left wing but also as socially conservative).

Comment: @Probably The question was asked about liberal vs. conservative beliefs in the United States, which, yes, includes the government having a larger vs smaller role but also includes many of the other things that I included in my answer.  I'll update the answer and establish the definition of conservatism.

Comment: You don't need a definition to convince me, I just didn't find what I was looking for, which is fine.

Comment: @Probably that's fine, I'm just wondering why you feel that the only conservative belief I highlighted was the government question?  I am aware that there are many different brands of liberalism and conservatism and that political beliefs are closer to a 2d graph than a 1d line, but conservative beliefs in the United States extend well beyond the scope of the role in government.

Comment: Well, because that's what defines economical left and right. I'd start a new question but I knew it would be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Probably OK now I understand.  You are right that the poll does not focus as strongly on fiscal matters, but the OP and the articles were talking about social issues as well.